# How to implement images for different resolutions

Tags: ios, xcode, image, resolution

I want to use resolution as a means to implement images for an iOS app.

iOS has the following resolutions for modern day devices:

iphone 5/SE:   640x1136 
iphone 6/7:    750x1334 
iphone 6/7+:   1242x2208 
ipad mini/air: 1536x2048 
ipad pro:      2048x2732 

The app that I'm building is Landscape only, so I'm looking at creating 5 images for every image, to match the necessary resolutions.

I struggle in how do I implement this within xcode using Image Sets. I can create 1 image set, and have it have a 3 slots for iphone, and also 3 slots for ipad. However, this only satisfies 3 of the 5 images that I want to create:

The iphone 6/7 @2x, iphone 6/7+ @3x, and the ipad pro at 2x.

Is there a way to implement additional slots for iphone 5 and the smaller Ipads?

I haven't been able to find a way, so I imagine that I would have to use a second Image Set, to add the 2 missing resolutions images. This would then require me to within code, have the viewcontroller, load different images based on the resolution of the device.

I'm okay with this additional requirement. My question would be is this the correct way of implementing this strategy? How would you implement this? And what might be some better strategies?



Notes: What I'm trying to avoid is limiting the number of constraints needed to get the views to look the way that I want. I started on an App, and I was using 2 images based on aspect ratio, and I think this is great, but the iphone 4 was throwing everything off. Then I learned that maybe I shouldn't worry about iphone 4 as it is outdated. So I'm either going to develop the UI from scratch using the 2 images method or attempt this 5 image method using resolution.

I'm a new developer so thank you for any assistance, sorry if I'm too verbose, I hope that this can help others as well, and I find that verbose is definitely the best way to be when learning. Thank you for any information!!!

Answer (score 1):

While you can't add additional slots to `.xcassets` you can implement [size classes](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Using_Size_Classes_to_Design_Universal_iOS_User_Interfaces) in your `.storyboard` files. This is an easy approach to design unique interface for every device. Using it you can design nice interface for iPhone 4 (however, it is outdated as you pointed in OP).

Comment: I've used size classes to implement different constraints depending on the categories of devices. If I had the 5 resolutions, there would be no need to scale down per device though. I guess I'm trying to see how one would implement that strategy.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what kind of images do you wanna use, but guessing that are just background images with gradient or plain colors, I think you can do this:

a) Create an image set including the highest resolution, the middle and the lowest one, maybe something like this:
1x: 640x1136 , 2x:1242x2208  and 3x: 2048x2732

b) Then use that image set using this code that assure that the image is correctly resized to the view:

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.theView.frame.size);
[[UIImage imageNamed:@"backgroundImageSet"] drawInRect:self.view.bounds];
UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
self.theView = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:image];
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: A few things, the iphone 5/SE is a @2x device, so I don't understand why you would add that resolution to 1x. Also the 5 images wouldn't be limited to just the background image. Lastly, I don't think I mentioned it, but all my imageviews will be loaded in the storyboard, and the image as well. The exception where code is needed is based on the device, I might need to change the image to match the res for iphone 5/SE and the smaller Ipads. I would be using the 5 images so that I don't need to resize them in code. Thanks for the response. whats with all the [ ] is that an objective-c thing?

Comment: I think you should explain more clearly and with more consistency what you wanna do. Now I'm not sure what you wanna do, it is guest that an image set with 1x: 640x1136 , 2x:1242x2208 and 3x: 2048x2732 will work well from iPhone 5 to iPad. On the other hand I definitely don't know how your interface looks, so, that's what I said, if it is just "for background". You can also handle this with just constraints, it shouldn't be many constrains, if it is the case.

Comment: So I reread my post and I don't see any consistency issues, I think I'm pretty clear on what I want. My comment isn't an attack at you. It is me trying to understand your answer. With that said, your recommendation for an image set is clearly flawed. The iphone 5 is never going to pull the 1x image, so having that resolution doesn't make sense. I also see that you put the resolution of the ipad pro as the 3x image. Ipad is a 2x, so it will never use the 3x image. Unless I'm wrong here, I have no idea how your solution answers my question. Again, I appreciate the feedback.

Comment: Sure, I'm not attacking too hehe. But I don't know if that is true "The iphone 5 is never going to pull the 1x image, so having that resolution doesn't make sense" but maybe you're right. Here I found a good article, maybe it can be of help: https://krakendev.io/blog/4-xcode-asset-catalog-secrets-you-need-to-know . Hope you can find the answer!

Comment: I'll have to read through that post, thanks for the link. I do believe it is true though. I believe that each device will pull from the 1x,2x,3x based on the type of device. You can test this out by creating images of different colors and run the simulator with different devices to see what it actually uses.